# DO block works fine, but function loops too many times?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, loops, plpgsql

I have a `vehicle_data` table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.vehicle_data (
  model_name text NOT NULL,
  record_date text NOT NULL,
  actual_inv_days real,
  forecasted_inv_days real[],
  CONSTRAINT vehicle_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (model_name, record_date)
)
```

Hence my table looks like this:

```
model_name   record_date  actual_inv_days  forecasted_inv_days
car1          1-2015         33            {22,33,11,22,33,44}
car1          2-2015         22            {25,35,10,22,30}
car1          3-2015         30            {32,30,20,11}
```

I would like to create a merged array for the user-selected month *n*, that shows the `actual_inv_days` from months *1..n*, and then the `forecasted_inv_days` of month *n* in one array. The result of `merged_array('car1',2015,3)` would be:

```
{33,22,30,32,30,20,11}
```

The below function worked just fine as a `DO` block, but when I modified it into a function it seems as if it **loops 68 times** more than necessary. **This is the happening with every function I write** and I don't know what to do.

```
-- DROP FUNCTION public.merged_array(text, integer, integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.merged_array(model text, yr integer, pivot integer)
  RETURNS real[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE actual_arr real[];
    element real;
    final_arr real[];
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..pivot 
      LOOP
    element:= (
          SELECT actual_inv_days
          FROM   vehicle_data
          WHERE  model_name = model
          AND split_part(record_date,'-',2)::int = yr
          AND split_part(record_date,'-',1)::int = i);
        -- append new element to existing array
        actual_arr:= actual_arr||element;
    END LOOP;
    final_arr:= actual_arr||(
         SELECT forecasted_inv_days
         FROM   vehicle_data
         WHERE  model_name= model
         AND split_part(record_date,'-',2)::int = yr
         AND split_part(record_date,'-',1)::int = pivot);
    RETURN final_arr;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What I tried to do is:

1. Create `actual_array` where we add the `actual_inv_days` as elements, for a particular `model` for a particular year (`yr`), with the chosen month as `pivot`.
2. Go month by month until 'pivot month' is reached, where model and year are satisfied.
3. Create a `final_array` which merges the `actual_array` and the `forecasted_inv_days` array.

Comment: You don't need a function,  nor a loop nor PL/pgSQL for this.

Comment: It would be more efficient to store your `record_date` in two integer columns so you can avoid the constant parsing of that column

Comment: This is how I would do it: https://rextester.com/RBIA47979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason in your code for *"loops 68 more times than necessary"*.

Be that as it may, like a_horse commented, all of this should be a single query. And your data model could profit from a redesign - especially the column `record_date`. A string of the pattern `1-2015` is among the least favorable ways to store that information. Does not even allow simple range queries. (`2015-01` would be more useful that way, but still suboptimal.)

Two `integer` columns would be better.
I would use a single `date`, truncated to the month, as it best fits the information to be stored. Occupies 4 bytes.

Then your table could look like this (everything else unchanged):

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_data (
  model_name  text NOT NULL
, record_date date NOT NULL
, actual_inv_days real
, forecasted_inv_days real[]
, CONSTRAINT record_date_truncated_to_month CHECK (date_trunc('month', record_date) = record_date)
, CONSTRAINT vehicle_data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (model_name, record_date)
);
```

Then you could wrap the query into this plain SQL function, made out to be a fall-in replacement for your old:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.merged_array(model text, yr integer, pivot integer)
  RETURNS real[] AS
$func$
   SELECT forecasted_inv_days
       || ARRAY (
            SELECT actual_inv_days
            FROM   vehicle_data
            WHERE  model_name = $1
            AND    record_date BETWEEN to_date(yr::text, 'YYYY')
                               AND     to_date(yr||'-'||pivot, 'YYYY-MM')
            ORDER  BY record_date
            )
   FROM   vehicle_data
   WHERE  model_name = model
   AND    record_date = to_date(yr||'-'||pivot, 'YYYY-MM')
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Of course you might also pass an actual date now (truncated to the month) ...

The manual about [`to_date()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) and about [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC).

About the ARRAY constructor used in the correlated subquery above:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Comment: The two integer columns would allow for conditions like `where (yr, mn) <= (2015,3)` which I find easier to read that the `to_date()` stuff in this context.

Comment: The sole reason for the `to_date()` stuff is to make it a fall-in replacement. I would rather pass a date parameter to begin with and have conditions like `WHERE record_date <= '2015-3-1'`. A date occupies 4 bytes in the table and enforces valid date values automatically. Makes indexes small and sorting simple and fast.

Comment: With just year and month, there is not much to validate - essentially only if the month is between 1 and 12. That can easily be achieved using a check constraint

Comment: Should work, too. Nothing against it really. I'd just rather use a `date` for the given reasons.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and Erwin, thank you so much you've been great help for me in this project I'm working on! I will change the record_date as you both suggested and try think more in terms of how to write simple queries rather than complicated functions from now on.